# Issue with timer with long signal handler (SIGALARM)

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, handler, signals

There is a timer which sends out signal SIGALARM every 1 sec. A signal handler which sleeps
2 sec is registered. What happens? Specifically, I have following code, in which the process runs multiple threads. It's quite interesting that with this long signal handler, it looks other threads are blocked from execution... Can anyone explain why this is the case?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //rand
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2

int init_timer(int real_time, int msec) {
    struct itimerval timeslice;
    timeslice.it_interval.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
    timeslice.it_interval.tv_usec = (msec % 1000) * 1000;
    timeslice.it_value.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
    timeslice.it_value.tv_usec = (msec % 1000) * 1000;
    setitimer(real_time ? ITIMER_REAL : ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &timeslice, NULL);
    return 0;
}

void install_handler(int signo, void(*handler)(int)) {
    sigset_t set;
    struct sigaction act;

    /* Setup the handler */
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(signo, &act, 0);

    /* Unblock the signal */
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, signo);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
    return;
}

void timerTest(int signo)
{
    printf("000\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("111\n");
}

void * threadTest(void * threadId)
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf("222\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int real_time = 1;
    int tick_msec = 10;
    init_timer(real_time, tick_msec);
    install_handler(real_time ? SIGALRM : SIGVTALRM, &timerTest);

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, threadTest, (void *) t);
        if (rc) {
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    void * status;
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[t], &status);
        if (rc) {
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

printout:

```
222
222
222
222
...
222
000
111
000
111
...
```

there will be no 222 after the first 111 occurs? why so?

Comment: It may also be relevant to include the operating system in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signal is delivered to a particular thread, so the signal handler runs in a particular thread (the thread the signal was delivered to).  If the signal is delivered to a thread writing out `222\n`, then that thread must stop writing out `222\n` and run the signal handler.  Your example signal handler takes a full second to run, so that's a full second during which that thread may not write out `222\n`.

Additionally, since you are using `printf` to write out all of these bytes, there is some locking being done in libc.  Since `printf` is not an "async signal safe" function, it's actually undefined what happens if you use it in a signal handler.  One possible explanation for the behavior you observe is this.  If the signal is delivered to a thread while that thread holds the stdout lock, then no other thread will be able to write to stdout until the handler returns and the lock can be released by the "normal" code running in that thread.  The signal handler can still write to stdout in this case, though, because the lock is an *rlock* which can be acquired repeatedly any particular thread.  This may vary from depending on the specific platform, C library, thread library, or phase of the moon, though.  Your example is easily converted to use write(2) though, which demonstrates more or less the same problem behavior, has more or less the same fix, and doesn't rely on undefined behavior.

If you `SIG_BLOCK` the timer signal in the `222\n` threads, then the signal handler will always run in the main thread and you will continue to get `222\n` output while the signal handler sleeps.

Seth also makes a great point about only using the safe functions in signal handlers.  Using any others means your program's behavior is undefined.

Comment: The fact that stdio locking is recursive does not mean it will work from a signal handler when the lock is already held in the calling thread. Recursive is a much weaker requirement than reentrant, and in fact neither stdio nor the locking it uses is usually reentrant.

Comment: Thanks, great point.  I've edited the answer to make it clear that the printf behaviors are undefined in this case, and pointed out an alternative which is somewhat equivalent, but which avoids undefined behavior.

Comment: The observed behaviour is actually due to `printf`'s lock. Changing `printf` to `write`, you get the saner behaviour that the children are writing `222` and occasionally `000`, `111` until all three threads end up sleeping on the signal handler (with further signals blocked) and no longer write `222`.

Answer (score 2):

Often times, signals (or at least that signal) is blocked when you are in a signal handler.  It is also a bad idea to do very much in a signal handler.  Generally you should set a variable or something like that, and then deal with the signal once you are in your normal codepath.

See sigaction's SA_NODEFER flag for a way to permit or deny receiving a signal inside a signal handler.

There is also a limited number of functions which are safe to call from inside a signal handler.  signal(7) man page describes this.  "A  signal  handler function must be very careful, since processing elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler calls an unsafe function, then **the behavior of the program is undefined**"

A program which calls an unsafe function from inside a signal handler is *broken*.  On some machines it will
    "work"; on others it will coredump.  It is permitted to do anything or
    nothing, including reformatting the disk, subjecting the user to
    scratchy Barry Manilow records played backwards, or dropping a tacnuke
    on Dallas.  Attempting to call an unsafe function puts the program into the twilight zone of undefined behavior.

With apologies to der Mouse.

Comment: Calling an unsafe function from a signal handler is sometimes valid, if you can guarantee that it did not interrupt an unsafe function. For example if the thread is just executing `for (;;) pause();` then you can do whatever you want in the signal handler.

Comment: If only I had said that.  Oh wait!  I did!

Comment: I was replying to this sentence: "A program which calls an unsafe function from inside a signal handler is broken." which is an oversimplification. Most naively written programs which do so *are broken*, but it's due to the programmer making an error not checking what other functions might be interrupted, not an inherent result of using async-signal-unsafe functions in a signal handler.

Answer (score -1):

It's incorrect to use `printf` in a signal handler.

Regarding the thread that is going to handle the SIGALARM you may find some useful information on signal blocking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679568/signal-handling-with-multiple-threads-in-linux). The post contains enlightening Linux kernel code. Essentially the signal is handled by the main thread if it wants to receive it. If not, it will be handled by any other thread that wants it. You could mask specific signals in a thread using `pthread_sigmask(3)`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I'll be doing that from now on