# Signal handling with multiple threads in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, ipc

In Linux, what happens when a program (that possibly has multiple threads) receives a signal, like SIGTERM or SIGHUP?

Which thread intercepts the signal? Can multiple threads get the same signal? Is there a special thread dedicated entirely to handling signals? If not, what happens inside the thread that is to handle the signal? How does the execution resume after the signal handler routine finishes?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is slightly nuanced, based on which version of the Linux kernel you are using.

Assuming 2.6 posix threads, and if you are talking about the OS sending SIGTERM or SIGHUP, the signal is sent to process, which is received by and handled by root thread. Using POSIX threads, you can also sent SIGTERM to individual threads as well, but I suspect you are asking about what happens when the OS sends the signal to the process.

In 2.6, SIGTERM will cause child threads to exit "cleanly", where as 2.4, child threads were left in an indeterminate state.

Comment: And what happens inside the root thread when a signal is received? Let's say I wrote a custom signal handler for SIGUSR1, and now I'm sending that signal to the process. The root thread will get that signal. Maybe it's in the middle of some function at that moment. What is going to happen?

Comment: if you have a handler setup, it will be treated as an interrupt, and program flow will halt and your custom handler will be executed. Once it's executed, control will return, assuming you haven't done anything to alter the normal flow (exit etc).

Comment: Note that this is specific to SIGUSR1, which IIRC doesn't interrupt system calls. If you tried this with SIGINT for example, it could interrupt a stream read, and when you went to return to reading, the stream may return an error that it was interrupted.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what is meant by "root thread".  Does this mean that the handler for SIGTERM will always run in the main thread, or can it run in any thread?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22005820/5267751), whic states that an arbitrary thread is chosen to handle the signal, contradicts your answer.

Answer (score 167):

[`pthreads(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) describes that POSIX.1 requires all threads in a process share attributes, including:

- signal dispositions

POSIX.1 also requires some attributes to be *distinct* for each thread, including:

- signal mask ([`pthread_sigmask(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html))
- alternate signal stack ([`sigaltstack(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html))

The Linux kernel's [`complete_signal`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/kernel/signal.c?h=v4.18.15#n898) routine has the following code block -- the comments are quite useful:

```
/*
 * Now find a thread we can wake up to take the signal off the queue.
 *
 * If the main thread wants the signal, it gets first crack.
 * Probably the least surprising to the average bear.
 */
if (wants_signal(sig, p))
        t = p;
else if (!group || thread_group_empty(p))
        /*
         * There is just one thread and it does not need to be woken.
         * It will dequeue unblocked signals before it runs again.
         */
        return;
else {
        /*
         * Otherwise try to find a suitable thread.
         */
        t = signal->curr_target;
        while (!wants_signal(sig, t)) {
                t = next_thread(t);
                if (t == signal->curr_target)
                        /*
                         * No thread needs to be woken.
                         * Any eligible threads will see
                         * the signal in the queue soon.
                         */
                        return;
        }
        signal->curr_target = t;
}

/*
 * Found a killable thread.  If the signal will be fatal,
 * then start taking the whole group down immediately.
 */
if (sig_fatal(p, sig) &&
    !(signal->flags & SIGNAL_GROUP_EXIT) &&
    !sigismember(&t->real_blocked, sig) &&
    (sig == SIGKILL || !p->ptrace)) {
        /*
         * This signal will be fatal to the whole group.
         */
```

So, you see that *you* are in charge of where signals are delivered:

If your process has set a signal's disposition to `SIG_IGN` or `SIG_DFL`, then the signal is ignored (or default -- kill, core, or ignore) for all threads.

If your process has set a signal's disposition to a specific handler routine, then you can control which thread will receive the signals by manipulating specific thread signal masks using [`pthread_sigmask(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html). You can nominate one thread to manage them all, or create one thread per signal, or any mixture of these options for specific signals, or you rely on the Linux kernel's current default behavior of delivering the signal to the main thread.

Some signals, however, are special according to the [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page:

> A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole
>   (e.g., when sent using [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)) or for a specific thread (e.g.,
>   certain signals, such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, generated as a
>   consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction are
>   thread directed, as are signals targeted at a specific thread using
>   [pthread_kill(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)).  A process-directed signal may be delivered to any
>   one of the threads that does not currently have the signal blocked.
>   If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the
>   kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.