# Is there any way to send signal to a thread from another process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I want to send a signal from a process to a thread that is created from **another process** (that have not created the thread.

What I know about this that:

- **raise**: sends signal to same process
- **pthread_kill** can send singal to a thread from same prcess, i.e that created that thread.
  you cannot use pthread_kill to send a signal to thread from another process.
- **kill** sends signal to a process

Is there any way to send signal to a thread from another process?

Hope I am clear!!!
NOTE: I am new to unix and threading

Comment: yesterday there was this question, with an example. i think it can be useful in your case http://stackoverflow.com/q/21381451/2549281

Comment: You can read about [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all).

Answer (score 1):

There is an appropriately named [`tkill(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tgkill.2.html):

> ```
> tkill, tgkill - send a signal to a thread
>
> tgkill() sends the signal sig to the thread with the thread ID tid
> ```

You can get a tid using [`gettid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html).

---

Beware: the concept of a TID and therefore everything having to do with one is Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Read About

1. `pthread_signal()`

Should set you in the right direction