# Which thread handles the signal?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I have 2 threads(thread1 and thread2). And I have signal disposition for `SIGINT`. Whenever `SIGINT` occurs thread 2 should handle the signal. For that I wrote below program

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sig_hand(int no)                  //signal handler
{
    printf("handler executing...\n");
    getchar();
}

void* thread1(void *arg1)              //thread1
{
    while(1) {
        printf("thread1 active\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void * thread2(void * arg2)           //thread2
{
    signal(2, sig_hand);

    while(1) {
        printf("thread2 active\n");
        sleep(3);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);
    while(1);
}
```

I compiled and and run the program. for every 1 second "thread1 active" is printing and for every 3 seconds "thread2 active" is printing.

Now I generated `SIGINT`. But its printing "thread1 active" and "thread2 active" messages like above. Again I generated `SIGINT`, now for every 3 seconds only "thread2 active" message is printing. Again I generated `SIGINT`, now all threads are blocked.

So I understood, for first time main thread executing signal handler. For second time thread1 executing handler and lastly thread2 executing signal handler.

How I can write the code like whenever signal occurs, only thread2 have to execute my signal handler?

Comment: `printf` is not a async-safe library call, meaning it must NOT be called by a signal handler... if it is, behaviour is unspecified (bad things can happen). `getchar` is not async-safe either, for that matter.

Comment: [Signal handling with multiple threads in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679568/signal-handling-with-multiple-threads-in-linux)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you send a signal to a process, which thread in the process will handle this signal is undetermined.

According to [`pthread(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads):

> POSIX.1 also requires that threads share a range of other attributes (i.e., these attributes are process-wide rather than per-thread):
>   ...
>   - signal dispositions
>   ...
>
> POSIX.1 distinguishes the notions of signals that are directed to the process as a whole and signals that are directed to individual threads. According to POSIX.1, a process-directed signal (sent using `kill(2)`, for example) should be handled by a single, **arbitrarily** selected thread within the process.

---

If you want a dedicated thread in your process to handle some signals, here is an example from [`pthread_sigmask(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask) shows you how to do it:

> The program below blocks some signals in the main thread, and then creates a dedicated thread to fetch those signals via sigwait(3). The following shell session demonstrates its use:

```
$ ./a.out &
[1] 5423
$ kill -QUIT %1
Signal handling thread got signal 3
$ kill -USR1 %1
Signal handling thread got signal 10
$ kill -TERM %1
[1]+  Terminated              ./a.out
```

> Program source

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Simple error handling functions */

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
        do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void *
sig_thread(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t *set = arg;
    int s, sig;

   for (;;) {
        s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "sigwait");
        printf("Signal handling thread got signal %d\n", sig);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;
    sigset_t set;
    int s;

   /* Block SIGQUIT and SIGUSR1; other threads created by main()
       will inherit a copy of the signal mask. */

   sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_sigmask");

   s = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &sig_thread, (void *) &set);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

   /* Main thread carries on to create other threads and/or do
       other work */

   pause();            /* Dummy pause so we can test program */
}
```

Comment: so you are trying say, we can't change threir behaviour

Comment: @SGG Change what behaviour to what?

Comment: well, you can `sigprocmask` or `pthread_sigmask` signals (process wide) but then `sigwait()` and handle in a thread of your choosing.

Comment: i want like if signal 2 occures thread2 should take care. if signal 3 occures thread1 should take care. I don;t want to random thread can't execute my specific signal

Comment: @SGG You could block all signals except the specific signal in the thread that that signal is allowed.

Comment: sorry I didn't get exactly how program works. could you add more info?

Comment: @SGG Which part of the code in my answer you does not understand? Did you read the manuals of related functions in that program?

Comment: ok understood. but sigwait is blocking call. Anyway i got logic.

Comment: Can I clear the blocked signals in the new thread and then use a blocking read or `sleep()` instead of `sigwait()`?

Comment: @basin blocking read, maybe. But why using `sleep()` instead of `sigwait()`?

Comment: @LeeDuhem I want the opposite. My library creates a thread and it should not interfere with the rest of the program, so I want to block all signals in it

Comment: @basin You can block all signals expect SIGKILL and SIGSTOP in your thread.

Answer (score 7):

Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [pthread(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) & [pthread_kill(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)  &  [sigprocmask(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) & [pthread_sigmask(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) -which you could use (to block `SIGINT` in unwanted threads). Read also a [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Avoid using signals to communicate or synchronize between threads. Consider e.g. mutexes ([pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) etc...) and condition variables ([pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) etc...).

If one of the threads runs an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (e.g. around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...) consider using [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

Comment: Half your answer is a link to a description elsewhere. Please summarize the links in your first paragraph and how they address the question here.