# Sending signals between threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals

I am new to multithreading. I have one doubt in passing signals between threads.

I am raising the signal in one thread (say thread 1).
I have a function (say f1) in thread 2 in which I register the signal.
Is it possible to exit from the function f1 which belong to thread2, when a signal has been raised in thread 1. If possible please let me know the way how to achieve it. My OS is Linux and I am using ACE threads.

Comment: It is better not to use signals. Use mutex etc. Signals can catch you with your trousers down

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22005827/841108). But avoid signals in that case.