# libuv signal handling in multithreaded programs

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, libuv

In a multithreaded C++ program where the main thread is executing a libuv event loop, is it guaranteed that this event loop thread is executing signal handlers registered using [`uv_signal_start`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/signal.html)?

**Background information:**

From http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html

> The I/O (or event) loop is [...] meant to be tied to a single thread.

But as we are in a multithreaded program, [signal handlers can be executed by other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22005820)

> According to POSIX.1, a process-directed signal (sent using kill(2), for example) should be handled by a single, arbitrarily selected thread within the process.

So my question is basically whether libuv signal handling works [as advertised](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/signal.html)

> Signal handles implement Unix style signal handling on a per-event loop bases.

even in multithreaded programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Yes, should work as advertised.

From my understanding of libuv's source code [unix/signal.c](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/48e04275332f5753427d21a52f17ec6206451f2c/src/unix/signal.c#L183-L221) there is a generic signal handler

```
static void uv__signal_handler(int signum) {
  uv__signal_msg_t msg;
  uv_signal_t* handle;
  int saved_errno;

  saved_errno = errno;
  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof msg);

  if (uv__signal_lock()) {
    errno = saved_errno;
    return;
  }

  for (handle = uv__signal_first_handle(signum);
       handle != NULL && handle->signum == signum;
       handle = RB_NEXT(uv__signal_tree_s, &uv__signal_tree, handle)) {
    int r;

    msg.signum = signum;
    msg.handle = handle;

    /* write() should be atomic for small data chunks, so the entire message
     * should be written at once. In theory the pipe could become full, in
     * which case the user is out of luck.
     */
    do {
      r = write(handle->loop->signal_pipefd[1], &msg, sizeof msg);
    } while (r == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    assert(r == sizeof msg ||
           (r == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)));

    if (r != -1)
      handle->caught_signals++;
  }

  uv__signal_unlock();
  errno = saved_errno;
}
```

in which a pipe `handle->loop->signal_pipefd[1]` is used to tell the handle's associated `loop` abount the incoming signal. Indeed, this generic signal handler can be called from any thread, however the libuv thread will then call the user's specific signal handler registered with `uv_signal_start` **in the event loop thread** (main thread in my setting) when it reads the `signal_pipefd[1]` in the next loop iteration.

This was for the unix source code and the windows [win/signal.c](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/48e04275332f5753427d21a52f17ec6206451f2c/src/win/signal.c#L80-L113) source has a similar mechanism.

So the answer should be yes, it should also work as advertised in a multithreaded setting, i.e. the registered handler will be executed by the loop thread.