# C++ On what thread signal callback is called?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I need to run a cleanup before exiting service upon termination (by Linux `systemctl stop my-srv`

I came up so far with 2 solutions:

```
void signal_callback(int code)
{
    _exit(0);
}

. . .
void main.. {
   signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback)
   fgetc(stdin); // wait for signal
}
```

on what thread the `signal_callback` is called? will it be the same thread which registered the callback? I mean if I call `signal` on main thread and then call `exit` in the `signal_callback` - will the application terminate gracefully?

Comment: If signals are implemented with exceptions then there's no threading involved.

Comment: sorry it doesnt mean anything to me - "implemented with exceptions". can you explain pls?

Comment: see [Execution of signal handlers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: apparently simple `pause` will do.. weird how nobody said that although id been asking for days..

Comment: Note that `exit` is not signal-safe.  Only the functions listed in [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) are safe to call from a signal handler (at least, without taking very specific precautions, which are mentioned in that man page), and `exit` is not among them (`_exit` is though).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signal handling with multiple threads in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679568/signal-handling-with-multiple-threads-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

> on what thread the signal_callback is called?

Depends on how you send the signal.

- If you send a signal using `raise`, then the callback will be called in the same thread.
- If you send a signal using `pthread_kill`, then the signal callback will be called in the thread that whose id was passed to `pthread_kill`.
- If you send a signal using `kill` then I think it's best to quote documentation:

  > POSIX.1 requires that if a process sends a signal to itself, and
  > the sending thread does not have the signal blocked, and no other
  > thread has it unblocked or is waiting for it in sigwait(3), at
  > least one unblocked signal must be delivered to the sending
  > thread before the kill() returns.

There will be differences if

> if I ... call exit in the signal_callback - will the application terminate gracefully?

No, `exit` is not an async safe function. It's not OK to call it from a signal handler.

Regarding edit: `_exit` is async safe so you may call it. But it won't call registered cleanup functions, nor would the stack be unwound, so I wouldn't describe it as "graceful" as such.

---

P.S. `main` must return `int`.

Comment: youd rather write 5 pages explanation why not rather than 2 lines of code showing how it should work.. i get it.

Comment: @BoppityBop You already wrote the code. I explained what your code would do. How would writing 2 lines of code explain what your code does?

Answer (score 1):

By default, signals are sent to the *process*; not to any specific threads that process may have. If there are multiple threadss, which thread handles signal(s) isn't specified by standards.

You can of course mask the signals so that certain threads don't receive them
or that only a specific thread handles the signals. See [pthread_sigmask](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) for Linux.

> if I call signal on main thread and then call exit in the signal_callback - will the application terminate gracefully?

What "gracefully" means depends on your program. If you setup a signal handler as you have, it'd simply exit upon receiving the signal. Whether that the process dies cleanly depends on what it was doing when it received signal such as whether any cleanup action is needed, resources need to be released (the ones not released automatically upon exit), etc.

Comment: gracefully means - I receive control so i can do what i need.

Comment: I had to edit the question. sorry. i didnt realise it is such a hard work to ask a c++ question. like shouting in a pillow