# Why are SIGSTOP/SIGCONT sent to all threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals

I have a process in Linux that has two POSIX threads running this function:

```c
void *
threadFunc(void *args)
{
    (void)args;
    long id = pthread_self();

    while (1) {
        printf("Hello from %li\n", id);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I send the process a `SIGSTOP`.  Both threads stop printing to the screen.  I send a `SIGCONT` and both threads resume their printing.

Based on [my understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679568/signal-handling-with-multiple-threads-in-linux) of how multithreaded processes handle signals, I would have thought that only one thread would have received the signal.  Why is it that both threads are stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` are special in that they can't be caught, blocked, or ignored (see [signal(7) man page for details](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)), and the behavior of `SIGSTOP` is to stop the process, not a single thread (so it technically doesn't matter which of your threads receives the signal, the whole process will still stop).

Comment: Does that apply to SIGCONT as well?  That is, what if I block that signal in only one thread?

Comment: @DanielWalker https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html